# Dynamically excluding first 5 minutes of data each hour of loading

Tags: oracle, datetime, timestamp, where-clause, sysdate

Data gets fetched from the below "CLAIMANT" table to load into another table. This happens every hour (6 am, 7am, 8am, etc.)

Say I need to write a WHERE CLAUSE that excludes the first 5 minutes of data from being loaded, each time the above operation occurs. The where clause will be added to the overall script that handles the operation

I have tried this, but it **excludes 0 records**, so it's not detecting the minute by minute differences of the "Filed_Date"

```
where FILED_DATE not between SYSDATE 
and ( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'hh24' ) + interval '5' minute )
```

What is the correct way to write the where clause to exclude the data I need to exclude

[image]

Comment: is this the correct code?
where FILED_DATE not between 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and (TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'hh24' ) + interval '5' minute)

Comment: It's a date datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original predicate has a start time and end time out of sync. If you run the query at 2:00 (sysdate), then the start time for your range is SYSDATE (2:00) and the end time is (TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH24')+interval '5' minute), or 2:05. If you run the query after 14:05, then your start time will actually be *after* your end time.

```
select to_date('2021-03-03 14:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') query_date, 
to_date('2021-03-03 14:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') start_time,
(trunc(to_date('2021-03-03 14:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),'HH24') + interval '5' minute) stop_time
from dual
union
select to_date('2021-03-03 14:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') query_date, 
to_date('2021-03-03 14:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') start_time,
(trunc(to_date('2021-03-03 14:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),'HH24') + interval '5' minute) stop_time
from dual;
```

Results:

```
QUERY_DATE           START_TIME           STOP_TIME            
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- 
2021-03-03T14:00:00Z 2021-03-03T14:00:00Z 2021-03-03T14:05:00Z 
2021-03-03T14:10:00Z 2021-03-03T14:10:00Z 2021-03-03T14:05:00Z
```

What you want is the data from 13:05 to 14:00, but the only data you are excluding is data you haven't received yet (after 14:00), so you get *everything* up to 14:00, or no data at all because of the mismatched start and stop times of your interval.

Try this, assuming the query runs on or after the top of the hour and you want to capture everything after the first five minutes of the previous hour up to the top of the current hour (i.e. the last 55 minutes of the previous hour):

```
where filed_date  
      between (trunc(sysdate,'HH24') - interval '55' minute) -- start time
      and (trunc(sysdate,'HH24'))                            -- end time
```

Now if the job time (sysdate) is any time between 14:00 and 14:59, then start time for the predicate is always 13:05 and stop time is always 14:00.

```
select to_date('2021-03-03 14:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') query_date,
(trunc(to_date('2021-03-03 14:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),'HH24') - interval '55' minute) start_time,
(trunc(to_date('2021-03-03 14:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),'HH24')) stop_time
from dual
union
select to_date('2021-03-03 14:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') query_date,
(trunc(to_date('2021-03-03 14:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),'HH24') - interval '55' minute) start_time,
(trunc(to_date('2021-03-03 14:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),'HH24')) stop_time
from dual;
```

Results:

```
QUERY_DATE           START_TIME           STOP_TIME            
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- 
2021-03-03T14:00:00Z 2021-03-03T13:05:00Z 2021-03-03T14:00:00Z 
2021-03-03T14:10:00Z 2021-03-03T13:05:00Z 2021-03-03T14:00:00Z
```

In general it is better to stay with positive assertions (i.e. BETWEEN);  negative conditions (i.e. *NOT* BETWEEN) tend to discourage the CBO from using indexes, if they exist.

Alternatively, if you ever wanted a larger timeframe and always wanted to exclude the first five minutes of any hour that happened to fall in the range, you could do this:

```
where filed_date
      between (sysdate - interval '3' hour) and sysdate
  and to_number(to_char(filed_date,'MI'),'99') > 5
```

This would limit the minutes portion of filed_date to 6 or more, effectively filtering out the first five minutes of *any* hour in the range.

Comment: Thanks, but kindly explain the "interval '55' minute" part as it relates the the "5 minute" exclude query

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain the interval, and the reason your original predicate didn't actually exclude any rows. As written, it was always either going to exclude nothing, or exclude *everything*, depending on whether sysdate fell in the first 5 minutes of the hour or not.

Comment: thank you. Now that I look at it, my query really does cover a time period that is in the future, when the data does not yet exist. To correct this, the query should pull in the latest 55 mins of data in the last hour. Your explanations and query make sense, thank you